# How to find pairs that don't have a reverse order pair in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

There are two tables.

Friend, attrbutes ID1,ID2, describing ID1 and ID2 are friends (If ID1 is friend of ID2, then ID2 is friend of ID1);

Likes, attributes ID1,ID2, describing ID1 likes ID2 (ID1 likes ID2 doesn't necessarily mean ID2 likes ID1).

I was asked to remove the Likes tuples for such situation that two students A and B are friends, and A likes B but not vice-versa.                                      The following is my query but it didn't remove any tuples:

```
delete from Likes where exists (
    select ID1,ID2 from Friend 
    where exists (select ID1,ID2 from Likes) 
    and not exists (select ID2,ID1 from Likes));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track.  The approach below is to use a positive `EXISTS` clause to check that a given like pair also has a friend relationship.  Then, it uses a negative `NOT EXISTS` clause to also assert that the reciprocal like relationship does not exist in the `Likes` table for that tuple.

```
DELETE
FROM Likes l1
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Friend f WHERE MIN(f.ID1, f.ID2) = MIN(l1.ID1, l1.ID2) AND
                                          MAX(f.ID1, f.ID2) = MAX(l1.ID1, l1.ID2)) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Likes l2 WHERE l1.ID1 = l2.ID2 AND l1.ID2 = l2.ID1);
```

Note that in the first `EXISTS` clause I make use of SQLite's scalar `MIN` and `MAX` functions.  In this case, we don't necessarily know in which order a given friend relationship or like relationship might be.  So, we can compare the smaller and larger of the two `ID` values, on either side.